# how to return a Point in this example

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, nullpointerexception

I am trying to return a Point from a circle.java class that extends a shape class. i keep getting a null pointer exception at the moment. i need to retrun the center point using the inherited getPoints(); method but the inhereted method returns a array and value to be returned from circle is not an array. how would i return the center point without makeing a seperate return method.
my Shape class is as follows

```
import java.awt.Point;

public abstract class Shape {
private String  name;
private Point[] points;
protected Shape(){};
protected Shape(String aName) {
    name = aName;
}

public final String getName() {
    // TODO Implement method
    return name;
}

protected final void setPoints(Point[] thePoints) {
    points = thePoints;
}

public final Point[] getPoints() {
    // TODO Implement method
    return points;
}

public abstract double getPerimeter();

public static double getDistance(Point one, Point two) {
    double x = one.getX();
    double y = one.getY();
    double x2 = two.getX();
    double y2 = two.getY();
    double x3 = x - x2;
    double y3 = y - y2;
    double ypow = Math.pow(y3, 2);
    double xpow = Math.pow(x3, 2);
    double added = xpow + ypow;
    double distance = Math.sqrt(added);
    return distance;
}
}
```

my circle class is a follows

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class Circle extends Shape{

private double radius;

public Circle(Point center, int aradius) {
super("Circle");

radius = aradius;
if(radius < 0){
    radius = 0;
}
else{
radius = aradius;
}

}

@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
double perim = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
return perim;
}
  public double getRadius(){
  return radius;
}

}
```

Comment: Can we see the exception trace

Comment: It's worth noting that your `Point` named `center` in the `Circle(Point, int)` constructor isn't used anywhere. Not sure if that's relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is simply to use the `setPoints` method from the `Shape`  class...

```
public Circle(Point center, int aradius) {
    super("Circle");
    //...
    setPoints(new Point[]{center});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a `NullPointerException` is because you never `setPoints` of `Shape`.

I'm not sure what `points` is supposed to contain but the only thing that would kind of make sense to me is all the points within the shape. Which IMO gets a bit tricky to determine with shapes like circles and determining a center point seems even trickier (although I guess for a circle it would pretty much be the middle point of the array depending on the order?).

(On second thought `points` could also contain whatever the subclass decides it should, like 1 center point for a circle and 4 points for a rectangle..)

Anyway you will have to fill the `points` array of `Shape` (by calling `setPoints`) with some data before you can use `getPoints`.